# DbContext with read-only set properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I was reading this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx and was trying to figure out how to create private setters (the section in the article **DbContext with read-only set properties** is right before the summary). How would you create private setters? I was playing around with different methods but nothing seemed to work. I am doing this because I need to group the original table based on a query I have because the original table is a heap and I need a primary key for the entity. So anytime a client asks for this table it is already grouped. Not even sure if this is the correct way to do that. Thanks.

**EDIT**: sorry for being vague. I am doing code first. For example there exists a SQL Table with JobNbr, Qty and Date and I need to group by JobNumber, sum on Qty and take the oldest expiration date, and that will be my entity since this table has no primary key. The way I am doing it now gives me the error below from a method I created in the DbContext class. I do have a EntityTypeConfiguration class. Do I do this in that class?

**EDIT:** : you might be wondering why I am doing this. Basically I need to get data from the heap and save it in another database. My original approach was `database.SqlQuery()` to get grouped rows from the heap, but sometimes I have too many parameters for execute_sql. So I decided to create an entity for the grouped query without tracking changes (since all I am doing is reading from the table and saving to another DB). See my post here with the issue I am having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106030/entity-framework-6-this-database-sqlquery-character-limitation-with-sp-executes. The only way I know to get around it is to create an entity (even though in this case the entity is a query and not a table).

> The entity or complex type
>   ' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Which approach? Code first? Model first? Database first?

Comment: Have read this question a few times and I still don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Basically I need to take a table, run a query to group on JobNbr so it is the key and I can use it as an entity. I could create a view in SQL, but I did not want to do this because the DB is on another server. How do I setup my context so anytime I put context.Entity, the entity that is returned is the grouped query? I set it up as an entity because EF send a sp_executesql any other way and I go over the character limit with my parameters. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106030/entity-framework-6-this-database-sqlquery-character-limitation-with-sp-executes)  Does that help?

Comment: I don't believe what you are trying to do is possible.

Comment: i think you are right. However, I guess I can make it an entity and then perform the group in a separate query. I was under the impression that if I specify JobNbr as the key column, EF would have a fit if it was not unique when I set it. However, EF does not seem to care, and since I am not tracking the entity and I am performing the aggregation in a service, I do not mind either.